# How to add TestNG method descriptions in ReportNG Surefire reports?

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin, reportng

I have Method descriptions provided in my scripts like this:

> @Test(description = "Activity Note", dependsOnMethods = {"XZO720"})

How can i get this method description in my ReportNG Surefire reports?

Answer (score 2):

Currently ReportNG includes test descriptions as tooltips that show when you hover over the test name (as in [this example report](http://reportng.uncommons.org/sample/suite1_test1_results.html)).  If you want something different you would have to modify ReportNG's Velocity templates.